# PHP MYSQL "Advanced" JOIN Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page that displays a list of events. By default all events are being displayed. The user can use an input field to filter that list. He can either enter a `city_code`, a `city_name` or a `city_state`. Here below my DB tables and their content:

**Locations**

```
city_code (pk)  
city_name  
city_state
```

**Events**

```
event_id (pk)  
event_name  
city_code(foreign key)
```

My idea to achieve what I want is:
1/ Filter the locations table based on the input value:

```
(SELECT * FROM locations WHERE city_code LIKE input OR city_name LIKE input or city_state LIKE input).
```

2/ Make a `JOIN` query between the events table and the filtered locations table.

My problem is that I know how to filter a table, I know how to make a join query, but not how to make both "together". I hope someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried just using both together?  You should find that it does as you desire.  The syntax you are looking for is one of the following

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM events
INNER JOIN locations
ON locations.city_code = events.city_code
AND (
    locations.city_code = ...
    OR 
    locations.city_name = ...
    OR
    locations.city_state = ...
)
```

Or the slightly less efficient but equally valid

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM events
INNER JOIN locations
ON locations.city_code = events.city_code
WHERE (
    locations.city_code = ...
    OR 
    locations.city_name = ...
    OR
    locations.city_state = ...
)
```

But really you should have given it a try before posting here.

Comment: Hello Simon. Thank you for the help. I tried with my very little knowledge but did not come with that syntax. Again thank you.